# Scala - how to filter a StructType with a list of StructField names?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I'm writing a method to parse schema and want to filter the resulting `StructType` with a list of column names. Which is a subset of StructField names of the original schema.

As a result, if a flag `isFilteringReq = true`, I want to return a StructType containing only StructFields with the names from the `specialColumnNames`, in the same order. If the flag is false, then return an original StructType.

```
val specialColumnNames = Seq("metric_1", "metric_2", "metric_3")
```

First I'm getting an original schema with pattern-matching.

```
val customSchema: StructType = schemaType match {
  case "type_1" => getType1chema()
  case "type_2" => getType2chema()
}
```

There are two problems:

**1** - I wasn't able to apply `.filter()` directly to the `customSchema` right after the curly brace. And geting a `Cannot resolve symbol filter`. So I wrote a separate method `makeCustomSchema`. But I don't need a separate object. Is there a more elegant way to apply filtering in this case?

**2** - I could filter the originalStruct but only with a single hardcoded column name. How should I pass the `specialColumnNames` to contains()?

```
def makeCustomSchema(originalStruct: StructType, isFilteringReq: Boolean, updColumns: Seq[String]) = if (isFilteringReq) {
  originalStruct.filter(s => s.name.contains("metric_1"))
} else {
  originalStruct
}

val newSchema = makeCustomSchema(customSchema, isFilteringReq, specialColumnNames)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a `Seq`, pass a `Set` and you can filter if the field is in the set or not.
Also, I wouldn't use a flag, instead, you could pass an empty `Set` when there's no filtering, or use `Option[Set[String]]`.
Anyway, you could also use the copy method that comes for free with case classes.
Something like this should work.

```
def makeCustomSchema(originalStruct: StructType, updColumns:Set[String]): StructType = {
  updColumns match {
    case s if s.isEmpty => originalStruct
    case _ => originalStruct.copy(
       fields = originalStruct.fields.filter( 
          f => updColumns.contains(f.name)))
  }
}
```

Usually you don't need to build structs like this, have you tried using the `drop()` method in DataFrame/DataSet ?

Comment: This approach resulted in an error `cannot resolve symbol fields; cannot resolve symbol name`

Comment: I amended the code... odd, intellij didn't complain about it when I typed it, it was missing `originalStruct` before `fields`. I tested this one.